# issue validating iPhone app archive

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to validate an app for testing ad-hoc on an iPod Touch running ios 6.1. It builds fine but when I try to archive I get the following errors:

- (null):  iPhone/iPod Touch: application executable is missing a required architecture.  At least one of the following architecture(s) must be present: armv7 (-19033)
- (null):  Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, contains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate. (-19011)
- (null):  Unable to extract entitlements from application: (null) (-19045)

I'm aware that there are other questions that relate very closely to this one, however they are all for outdated versions of xcode or simply do not work. If there is anything else I can do to clarify my problem let me know.

Comment: Did you create the provisioning profile and added your app and your certificates there? If so, make sure to add those profiles in xCode organizer. After that, make sure your are code signing your target, and make sure your target is iPhone inside your Projects configuration file, under Summary tab. Let us know if you're missing some of these steps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found out what the issue was, the plist in my project was not the plist that my app was using. So when I changed the plist and provisioning profile to use a different bundle name I found the error. Thanks for your quick reply though!